# difference between recursive function and using a stack in terms of use of memory

Tags: algorithm, memory, graph

I want to know difference between recursive function and using a stack in terms of use of memory usage.
Say for large [DFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) which will be more efficient.

Comment: A compiler transform your recursive program into an iterative one, thus creating an explicit stack :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An explicit stack data structure should use *slightly* less memory in theory, as a recursive function will always have some additional overhead per invocation, for return address, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I will assume you want to discuss the difference between two approaches of the same algorithm. We have a graph *G = (V, E)* where *V* is a set of vertices and *E* is a set of vertex pairs and we run a depth-first-search (DFS) on the graph by either:

- Using a recursive approach where the `visit` method recursively calls itself.
- Using an explicit stack in a loop.

Both methods, on the large, use the same amount of space, *O(d)* where *d* is the depth of the DFS search tree (it is bounded by the longest possible non-cycling path in the graph.

Usually an explicit stack will use *slightly* less memory as Paul R writes. Another important point is that in many languages, the function call-stack is severely limited and will abort the program if it grows too large. The explicit stack, managed in the heap, does not pose a similar problem. To get the *slightly* less memory usage though, you will have to represent the stack as an array though. If you represent it as a linked list, it will probably not be better. It may even be slightly worse.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to go the other way, at least in compiled languages. Recursive functions, written with an eye to efficieny, can do better than an explicit stack. A compiler can use the stack-frame-manipulation primitives of CPUs that possess them to do things more efficiently.

This view is supported by "Garbage collection is fast, but a stack is faster", by James S Miller and Guillermo Rosaz: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.18.2789

Comment: I think u meant efficiency in terms of time. I asked in terms of memory